# Asymptotic behavior of the square Generalized Laguerre polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

The asymptotic begavior of the Generalized Laguerre polynomial is given in the Book " Formulas and theorems in the special functions of mathematical physics. Berlin: Springer-Verlag; 1966" in page 245
$$L_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x)=\frac{e^{x/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}x^{(2 \alpha+1)/4}}n^{(2\alpha-1)/4} \cos(2 \sqrt{nx}-\pi \frac{2 \alpha+1}{4})+ \mathcal{O}(n^{2 \alpha-3)/4}) \mbox{ for } n \longrightarrow + \infty$$
I have two suggestions for the expression of the asymptotic behavior of $(L_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x))^{2}$ for $n \longrightarrow + \infty$, they are the following

- $$(L_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x))^{2}=\frac{e^{x}}{\pi x^{(2 \alpha+1)/2}}n^{(2\alpha-1)/2} (\cos(2 \sqrt{nx}-\pi \frac{2 \alpha+1}{4}))^{2}+ \mathcal{O}(n^{(2 \alpha-3)/2})$$
- or $$ (L_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x))^{2}=\mathcal{O}(n^{(2\alpha-3)/4})$$
  In the second point, can we write $(L_{n}^{(\alpha)}(x))^{2} \leq M(n^{(2\alpha-3)/4})$ for some $M > 0$? Are one of those suggestions is true? If not how can i found the asymptotic behavior of the square generalized Laguerre polynomial?
  Best regards and thanks.

Comment: neither of your two expressions is correct; what you have is that $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)=n^{(2\alpha-1)/4}f_n^{(\alpha)}(x)[1+{\cal O}(n^{-1/2}]$, so if you square it you get $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)^2=n^{(2\alpha-1)/2}f_n^{(\alpha)}(x)^2[1+{\cal O}(n^{-1/2}]$ --- this is your first expression with ${\cal O}(n^{(2\alpha-3)/2})$ replaced by ${\cal O}(n^{\alpha-1})$.

Comment: so this is what i must do in that case